# Error when trying to connect to docker container using grpc

Tags: docker, go, networking, protocol-buffers, grpc

I try to connect to a docker container using golang grpc but run into the following problem. OS I use is Linux.

My .proto file appears like this:

```
syntax = "proto3"; 
package reverse;
service Reverse {
    rpc Do(Request) returns (Response) {}
}
message Request {
    string message = 1;
}
message Response {
    string message = 1;
}
```

Client main.go:

```
func main() {
    opts := []grpc.DialOption{
        grpc.WithInsecure(),
        grpc.WithBlock(),
    }
    args := os.Args
    conn, err := grpc.Dial("127.0.0.1:5300", opts...)
    if err != nil {
        grpclog.Fatalf("fail to dial: %v", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    log.Info("Connect finished")
    client := pb.NewReverseClient(conn)
    request := &pb.Request{
        Message: args[1],
    }
    response, err := client.Do(context.Background(), request)
    if err != nil {
        grpclog.Fatalf("fail to dial: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(response.Message)
}
```

Server main.go:

```
func main() {
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":5300")
    if err != nil {
        grpclog.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
    }
    opts := []grpc.ServerOption{}
    grpcServer := grpc.NewServer(opts...)
    pb.RegisterReverseServer(grpcServer, &server{})
    grpcServer.Serve(listener)
}
type server struct{}
func (s *server) Do(c context.Context, request *pb.Request) (response *pb.Response, err error) {
    n := 0
    rune := make([]rune, len(request.Message))
    for _, r := range request.Message {
        rune[n] = r
        n++
    }
    rune = rune[0:n]
    for i := 0; i < n/2; i++ {
        rune[i], rune[n-1-i] = rune[n-1-i], rune[i]
    }
    output := string(rune)
    response = &pb.Response{
        Message: output,
    }
    return response, nil    
}
```

It is expected that the client can receive the reverse of the string passed by command line argument. This works fine, and I try to pack the server into a docker image.
Dockerfile:

```
FROM scratch
ADD . /bin/
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/server"]
EXPOSE 5300
```

Here is my problem: When I run the docker container with argument `-p 5300:5300` then the correct value can be returned. Now I run the container without port mapping. I find the container's IP address by `docker inspect` and its address is 172.17.0.2. Then I change the IP address in `grpc.Dial` function in Client main.go to 172.17.0.2. I run the client again and find the program is stuck at `client.Do` function. So what I want to ask is that how can I connect to docker container using direct IP address?

Comment: > Now I run the container without port mapping.
Why would you do this? And what are you trying to achieve? If you remove the port mapping, you can access that container only from the docker network (e.g. from another container in the same network), and this network can be configured in different ways.